# One Step Checkout plugin - Move VAT row below Delivery

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onestepcheckout

I want to move the VAT row below the delivery cost in the One Step Checkout review your order section. What would be the best approach to rearrange them?

[image]

Thanks in advanced for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change this from `Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Sales -> Checkout Totals Sort Order`.

Sample:
[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure this would work because he's using Onestepcheckout, but if it does, your solution is way easier than mine! :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you'd need to reorder the totals array itself prior to the for loop which outputs them.

The foreach loop starts as follows:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getTotals() as $total): ?>
```

The `$this->getTotals()` returns an array of totals that is pre-sorted. As you are looking for a different order, then you'll need to modify this declaration.

Firstly, you'll need to ascertain the keys and the current order:

```
<?php var_dump(array_keys($this->getTotals())); ?>
```

That code will output the order of the totals along with their identification keys.

Now you can look at re-ordering them. Change your `foreach` loop to resemble this:

```
<?php
// Get all totals
$all_totals = $this->getTotals();

// Create a new array of totals (empty)
$totals = array();

// Explicitly set the order of the totals into the totals array
$totals[0] = $all_totals['subtotal'];
$totals[1] = $all_totals['shipping'];
$totals[2] = $all_totals['tax'];
$totals[3] = $all_totals['grand_total'];

// Loop through your new order
foreach ($totals as $total): ?>
```

You'll need to adapt your own total keys into this format, and ensure that the indices of your new `$totals` array are correct for what you want.